# how can I validate property before send my data to database im new on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to do is make a validation when is not empty my array then it will be display successfully added, but before that I want to implement if stock is greater than min_stock and if max_stock is less greater than stock then do some msg. then if not duplicate .... to check if it's duplicate it works , but it isnt working when I try to implement this

```
if ($stock > $min_stock) {
            $this->json(array('min_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'));
        }elseif ($max_stock < $stock) {
            $this->json(array('min_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al max'));
        }else{
        }
```

controller

```
public function addProduct(){
        $descripcion = $this->input->post('description');
        $cost_price =  $this->input->post('cost_price');
        $selling_price = $this->input->post('selling_price');
        $wprice = $this->input->post('wprice');
        $min_stock = $this->input->post('min_stock');
        $stock = $this->input->post('stock');
        $max_stock = $this->input->post('max_stock');
        $data = array(
            'descripcion' => $descripcion,
            'precio_compra' => $cost_price,
            'precio_venta' => $selling_price,
            'precio_mayoreo' => $wprice,
            'existencia_minima' => $min_stock,
            'existencia' => $stock,
            'existencia_maxima' => $max_stock
        );
        //$this->json(array('msg' => 'successfully added'));
        //$this->json(array('duplicate' => 'product already exists'));

        if (!empty($this->products->addProduct($data))) {
            -->> before this $this->json(array('msg' => 'successfully added'));
        }else{
            $this->json(array('duplicate' => 'product already exists'));
        }

        // the below code how can I implement into 
        if ($stock > $min_stock) {
            $this->json(array('min_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'));
        }elseif ($max_stock < $stock) {
            $this->json(array('min_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al max'));
        }else{
        }
    }
```

model

```
 public function addProduct($data){
        $this->db->select('descripcion');
        $this->db->from('storelte_articulos');
        $this->db->where('descripcion',$data['descripcion']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows() == 0 ? $this->db->insert('storelte_articulos',$data) : false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code after $data array in your controller as following:

```js
if ($stock > $min_stock) { 
   $this->json(array('min_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al min'));
}elseif ($max_stock < $stock) {
   $this->json(array('min_stock' => 'el stock no puede ser mayor al max'));
} else {
    if (!$this->products->isExistsProduct($data)) {
      $this->products->addProduct($data)
      $this->json(array('msg' => 'successfully added'));
    }else{
        $this->json(array('duplicate' => 'product already exists'));
    }
}
```

Rewrite your **Model** as following:

```js
public function isExistsProduct($data){
        $this->db->select('descripcion');
        $this->db->from('storelte_articulos');
        $this->db->where('descripcion',$data['descripcion']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows() == 0 ? false : true;
    }

public function addProduct($data){
        $this->db->insert('storelte_articulos',$data)
    }
```

Comment: it's still sending the data before the full validation is right

Comment: Do you want to pass the min_stock message along with msg into $this->json ?

Comment: i want to validate if stock is greater than min , if max is lss greater than stock , before send the data

Comment: Please try the rewritten code. rewrite your controller and model